# Python and FFmpeg Automation Giving Error

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a list of videos in a folder. I want to use ffmpeg for all of them at once. But my script is giving an error. I couldn't find why.

My video list like these:

> 713 - The.Devils.Advocate.1997.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4' 
>   714 -The.Terminal.2004.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4'
>   363-The.King's.Speech.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264-.mp4"

My code is here:

```
import os

path = './'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if (filename.endswith(".mp4")): #or .avi, .mpeg, whatever.
        folder_name = str(filename)[0:3]
        try:
            os.mkdir(folder_name)

        os.system("ffmpeg -i " + filename + " -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls " + folder_name + "/HD.m3u8")
    else:
        continue
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
  File "hlsyarat.py", line 12
    os.system("ffmpeg -i " + filename + " -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls " + folder_name + "/HD.m3u8")
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `try` is supposed to have matching `except` or `finally`.

Comment: Ah that's the problem Thank you